# why wouldn't application of recursive ld rpath work?

Tags: ld

My executable `oom`, (recursively) requires a shared library `libvpncli.so` which in turn requires `libvpnapi.so`.

When I try to link `oom`, I get this:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libvpnapi.so, needed by /path/to/libvpncli.so, not found
```

However, `libvpncli.so` was correctly compiled with `-rpath` options to know how to find `libvpnapi.so`.  I checked this by hand, and also `ldd` shows it:

```
$ldd /path/to/libvpncli.so
libvpnapi.so => /path/to/libvpnapi.so
```

Then why can't `ld` for `oom` find `libvpnapi.so` ?

Edit - to answer n.m. 's points:

"specifies a run-time path"

No. `rpath` is also used during linking to check that all the symbols will be resolved. Anyway, I am not talking about runtime in this question, but about linking.

Indeed, if I add `rpath` directly to `oom` link line to point to `libvpnapi.so`, the warning disappears.

But I don't want to do that (for other reasons).  Instead, I need to understand why the above _does_not_ work.

"have to specify its directory with -rpath or (perhaps better) -rpath-link at the command line when linking oom"

No. On a different system, the above scheme *does* work, without directly specifying `-rpath` on `oom` link line, but working indirectly, recursively.

My question is, why doesn't it *always* work, on every system? What could be the reason why it does not work, when the evidence is that it should, as shown in my question.

Comment: rpath embedded in a shared object is for the dynamic loader and specifies a run-time path.

Comment: To find libvpnapi.so, you have to specify its directory with -rpath or (perhaps better) -rpath-link at the command line when linking oom.

Comment: @n.m. see edits above

Comment: I guess I was mistaken, as the ld manual says: *For a native ELF linker, the directories in "DT_RUNPATH" or "DT_RPATH" of a shared library are searched for shared libraries needed by it. The "DT_RPATH" entries are ignored if "DT_RUNPATH" entries exist.* So GNU ld does look at the embedded rpath after all. Perhaps one of your systems is not using GNU ld.

Comment: @n.m. no, they are both Linux CentOS 7.5, and I checked _everything_ that is mentioned in the `ld` man page about the order of looking at libraries. But it does not say precisely how things work recursively. I guess I am going to have to study the recursive situation carefully, which I am not keen to do :)

Comment: Why, *the directories in "DT_RUNPATH" or "DT_RPATH" of a shared library are searched for shared libraries needed by it* seems like a pretty clear description of what happens. Do a `objdump -a -x libvpncli.so | grep PATH` on both systems.